# Wireless router with built-in VPN client?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

Is there such a Wifi router that also has a built-in L2TP/IPsec VPN client? I want to share a VPN connection from multiple wifi clients but without having to setup VPN on each and individual client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a VPN router. DLink makes several like this one [here](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=564). I'm certain Netgear and Linksys make them as well, they are often used by remote offices to connect to a larger corporate network.

Comment: It was pointed out to me that I should just include the product search link for the full line of VPN routers: [http://www.dlink.com/search/?qry=vpn%20router](http://www.dlink.com/search/?qry=vpn%20router)

Comment: I cannot find information that suggests that, e.g. DIR 330, can connect to a remote L2TP/IPsec server and allow wireless clients to access internet via the remote VPN server

Comment: I can understand the confusion as the VPN router has two modes - a client mode that achieves the goals you are discussing and a host mode that allows VPN connections to be made to your network.
From the feature list: PPTP/L2TP Server/Client
You can also download the manual [here](ftp://ftp.dlink.com/Gateway/dir330/Manual/dir330_manual_110.zip). Page 32 shows the settings you would need to change.

Comment: found out that DD-WRT can also do this (and some other "generic" router firmware products).

Answer (score 0):

Alex, i am also in search of a router which does what you want. you will need to buy a router which has an openvpn client built in. Dlink DSR-500 does the job, but is available only in the US. Outside of the US you could consider lyconsys' Mini VPN Router as it has an openvpn client in it. However, lyconsys' routers are made in Germany and hence would be expensive. Hence if price is a constraint then you could consider buying a Cisco Linksys E3000 router (Cost around US$150/-approx.) then download the dd-wrt v2 firmware from www.dd-wrt.com and flash it on to the Linksys router. Please do your study on both the router and the dd-wrt firmware before flashing it as you could end up in have a nice looking brick and by simply trying to flash the firmware of the router you loose the manufacturer's warranty. I have requested for the Mini VPN Router for testing. Will post my findings here. All the best. - Ramesh